# A question about the expression of Riemann tensor in Landau & Lifshitz

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, curvature

I was reading Landau & Lifshitz *"The Classical Theory of Fields"* and there is a expression at the beginning of section 92-Properties of the curvature tensor I don't understand. The author expresses the covariant curvature tensor $$R_{iklm}=g_{in}R^n_{klm}\tag{92.0}$$ to the following expression:
$$
R_{iklm}=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{k}\partial_{l}g_{im}+\partial_{i}\partial_{m}g_{kl}-\partial_{k}\partial_{m}g_{il}-\partial_{i}\partial_{l}g_{km})+g_{np}(\Gamma^n_{kl}\Gamma^p_{im}-\Gamma^n_{km}\Gamma^p_{il}).\tag{92.1}
$$
I checked the first term on the righthand side, but the second term seems means
$$
g_{in}(\Gamma^n_{pl}\Gamma^p_{km}-\Gamma^n_{pm}\Gamma^p_{kl})=g_{np}(\Gamma^n_{kl}\Gamma^p_{im}-\Gamma^n_{km}\Gamma^p_{il})
$$
and I don't understand why this relation hold?

Answer (score 0):

The second term should be worked out as follows:
$g_{in} (\Gamma^n_{pl} \Gamma^p_{km} - \Gamma^n_{pm} \Gamma^p_{kl})$ L.H.S.
Compose $g_{in}$ with $\Gamma^n_{pl}$ and $\Gamma^n_{pm}$
$(\Gamma_{ipl} \Gamma^p_{km} - \Gamma_{ipm} \Gamma^p_{kl})$
Relabel the summation index $p$ as $n$
$(\Gamma_{inl} \Gamma^n_{km} - \Gamma_{inm} \Gamma^n_{kl})$
Raise the summation index $n$ in the first $\Gamma$ of each product composing with $g_{np}$
$g_{np} (\Gamma^p_{il} \Gamma^n_{km} - \Gamma^p_{im} \Gamma^n_{kl})$
Swap the $\Gamma's$ in each product, post a $-$ sign and exchange the order of the products
$-g_{np} (\Gamma^n_{kl} \Gamma^p_{im} - \Gamma^n_{km} \Gamma^p_{il})$ R.H.S., but with the opposite sign

I validated the expression up to a sign.